# Como saber quanto % do conteúdo foi baixado, em uma requisição Ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, http

Preciso fazer aquela animaçãozinha, como no Youtube, da barrinha de progresso que aparece no topo.

Como faço para saber quanto do conteúdo foi baixado, para ter uma base para a barra de progresso?

Eu não queria fazer uma animação "estática", de dois pontos, eu quero ela coerente com o progresso real de carregamento.

Comment: Talvez isso ajude: https://github.com/englercj/jquery-ajax-progress

Answer (score 1):

Você tem que pegar as funções que te retornam as seguintes informações:

- Quantidade carregada
- Quantidade total a ser carregada

Após você receber, é somente fazer o calculo de porcentagem:

```
(quantidade_carregada * 100) / quantidade_total_a_ser_carregada
```

Isso te dará quantos % (porcento) já foi carregado do arquivo.

Veja esse plugin: [AjaxSubmit](https://www.sanwebe.com/2012/06/ajax-file-upload-with-php-and-jquery). Nesse link tem uma barra de progresso de upload bastante simples:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
var options = { 
    target:   '#output',   // target element(s) to be updated with server response 
    beforeSubmit:  beforeSubmit,  // pre-submit callback 
    success:       afterSuccess,  // post-submit callback 
    uploadProgress: OnProgress, //upload progress callback 
    resetForm: true        // reset the form after successful submit 
}; 

 $('#MyUploadForm').submit(function() { 
    $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);            
    return false; 
 }); 


});
```

No código abaixo recebe o variável **percentComplete** onde é a porcentagem atual do upload. Mas funciona da mesma forma como a conta que te passei no inicio do post, a diferença é que aqui ele já traz calculado para você na variável **percentComplete**

```
function OnProgress(event, position, total, percentComplete)
{
    //Progress bar
    $('#progressbox').show();
    $('#progressbar').width(percentComplete + '%') //update progressbar percent complete
    $('#statustxt').html(percentComplete + '%'); //update status text

}
```

Comment: Eu estou falando do download, do que foi baixado do lado cliente... Isso aí eu já sabia, amigo.